# Is this a good way to use dlls? (C++?)

Tags: c++, performance, dll

I have a system that runs like this:

main.exe runs sub.exe runs sub2.exe

and etc. and etc...

Well, would it be any faster of more efficient to change sub and sub2 to dlls?

And if it would, could someone point me in the right direction for making them dlls without changing a lot of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLLs would *definitely* be faster than separate executables. But keeping them separate allows more flexibility and reuse (think Unix shell scripting).

[This](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855) seems to be a good DLL tutorial for Win32.

As for not changing code much, I'm assuming you are just passing information to theses subs with command line arguments. In that case, just rename the `main` functions, export them from the DLL, and call these renamed "`main`" functions from the main program.

Answer (score 3):

DLL really are executables too. They comply to the PE standard which covers multiple common file extensions for windows, like .exe, .dll, .ocx...

When you start 2 executables they each get their own address space, their own memory and such. However when you load an executable and a dll, the dll is loaded into the process space of the executable so they share a lot of things.

Now depending on how your 3 executables communicate together (if they even communicate together), you might have to rewrite some code. Basically the general approach to having dlls is to simply call the dll function from inside your program. This is usually much simpler than interprocess communication

Answer (score 2):

If your program (main.exe) is merely starting programs that really have nothing to with it, keep doing what you're doing. If sub.exe and sub2.exe contain functionality that main.exe would benefit from, convert them to dlls, so main.exe can call functions in them.

When it comes to efficiency, it depends on how large sub.exe and sub2.exe are. Remember that loading a dll also implies overhead.

Comment: The overhead of loading a DLL is much smaller than starting an exe

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors to take into consideration. For starters, how often do you run that sequence, and how long is the job executed by the other executables? If you do not call them very often, and the job they execute is not very short, the load time itself becomes insignificant. In that case, I'd say go with whatever fits the other needs. If, OTOH, you do call them quite a lot, I'd say make them DLLs. Load them once, and from that point onward every call is as fast as a call to a local function.

As for converting an exe to a dll - it should not be very complicated, but there are some points when working with dlls that require special care: using dllmain for initialization has some limitations a regular main doesn't have (synchronization issues); you'll have to keep in mind a dll shares the address space with the exe; CRT versions discrepencies might cause you grief [and so on](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/DLL_bestprac.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how often they are run. That if, is the tear-up/tear-down of processes is a significant cost.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be safer to convert them to dll's to prevent the user from accidentally running sub1 or sub2 without main starting them?