# Import a DLL with C++ (Win32)

Tags: c++, dll, winapi, import

*How do I import a DLL (minifmod.dll) in C++ ?*

I want to be able to call a function inside this DLL. I already know the argument list for the function but I don't know how to call it.

**Is there a way of declaring an imported function in C++ like in C# ?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The c# syntax for declaring an imported function is not available in c++.  Here are some other SO questions on how to use DLLs:

- [Explicit Loading of DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253769/explicit-loading-of-dll)
- [Compile a DLL in C/C++, then call it from another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847396/compile-a-dll-in-c-c-then-call-it-from-another-program)
- [Calling functions in a DLL from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539358/calling-functions-in-a-dll-from-c)
- [Call function in c++ dll without header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554551/call-function-in-c-dll-without-header)
- [How to use dll's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345671/how-to-use-dlls)
- [Is this a good way to use dlls? (C++?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080662/is-this-a-good-way-to-use-dlls-c)

Answer (score 6):

If the DLL includes a COM type library, you can use the #import statement as such:

```
#import dllname.dll
```

Otherwise, you'll need to link with an import library, and you'll need to provide a function prototype for your compiler. Typically the import library and a header file with the prototypes are provided by the DLL developer. If you're not, they can be very difficult to produce - **unless** you already know the argument list for the function, which you say you do. Instructions can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313), amongst other places.

Answer (score 3):

At runtime you can call [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and then call [`GetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to access the function from a DLL. You will need to cast this address to a prototype you define with `typedef` . See the example at `GetProcAddress` documentation page.