# Calling Delphi function in VC Project

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, dll

I created a function in delphi as below:
`function CheckResult():integer; stdcall; export;`

The compiler is Delphi 64 and the output is CheckFunctions.dll

Then
in the VC++ project (VS 2012),
I write:
`extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall CheckResult();`

and use it in a function, then I get the compiler error in C++ project:

> error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CheckResult referenced in function *****

How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: You can use NTCore CFF Explorer to look into your DLL and check if it is really win64 and if it really exports your function and under which name it was exported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dllimport in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041149/how-to-dllimport-in-c)

Comment: Useful articles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041149/how-to-dllimport-in-c and http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/dlluse.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an import library (.lib file) for the DLL. That's why the linker is giving that error message. Unfortunately Delphi won't generate a .lib file which is a bit of a weakness in my view.

You can solve the problem by either:

1. Linking with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.
2. Generate a suitable .lib file.

Option 2 is easy enough. Create a fake DLL project in Visual Studio. Arrange for it to export the same functions as your Delphi DLL. Implement these functions with empty stubs. Use a .def file rather than __declspec(dllexport) to avoid name decoration of your exports.

It's really obvious really. Make a fake DLL that has an identical interface to the real DLL. The same name, the same functions. The fake DLL needs no implementation because all you are doing is getting the MS tools to make the .lib file that Delphi cannot.

More details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313

---

FWIW I believe that the Delphi export modifier is ignored. Use an exports clause instead.

Comment: weakness ? does def-file has any information that is not already contained in .dll ? i think that C++ relying on that def file is rather weakness. DRY.

Comment: @Arioch You aren't following. The weakness is that Delphi doesn't export the .lib file. Doing so would make it easier to interop with other languages. The fact that .lib files may be needless is irrelevant. C++ compilers use them and so Delphi would be better if it made them.

Comment: There is an easier way to create a .lib import file for an existing .dll file. Use VC's command-line [LIB](http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0b9xe492.aspx) utility, which is similar to C++Builder's command-line IMPLIB utility.

Comment: According to the MS KB article that I linked to, this won't get
the job done for stdcall functions. You need to stub out the
functions in that case.

Comment: You still use LIB to create the actual .lib file after compiling the stub, so my comment still stands.

Comment: @Remy Your comment starts: "There is an easier way." How is it easier?

Comment: Loaidng with GetProcAddress is not only easier, it fails in a nicer way.  Implibs will result in your main app failing to start if the DLL cannot be found. Hardly any fun. Go with David's option #1, dear original poster.

Comment: @WarrenP: if you use delay loading, you get the best of both worlds. Static linking to DLL functions without having to call `GetProcAddress()` manually (still requires an import .lib), and run-time loading of the DLL when an exported function is called for the first time rather than at process creation.

Comment: Thank you, with your idea, I can call the delphi dll with LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress successfully. But I haven't try the second way, does it mean that I creat a fake c++ project which has the same deaclearation as delphi and compile it, then VS will generate the lib file automaticlly?

Comment: You generate it with a command line tool. In C++ Builder it's IMPLIB.EXE, in Visual C++ it's LIB.EXE. Moskito-x's answer below has all the detailed blow by blow instructions on that technique.  Personally I just stick with the manual stuff. Let's me load when I want to load, check for errors, set a global variable saying "Feature Plugin X enabled", etc.

Comment: @Warren Moskito's answer doesn't get the job done. With stdcall you need to export functions with decorated names with @n suffixes. In order to avoid that and use plain names you need to use the stubbing method that I described.

Comment: True but he does describe the implib tool a bit more than your answer did. So does Remy.

Comment: @Warren I chose not to because it doesn't do the job. Because of decoration issues. Would work well with cdecl functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use VC's command-line [LIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0b9xe492.aspx) utility to create a VC-compatible import .lib file for the DLL, then add that file to your VC project.

Comment: According to the MS KB article that I linked to, this won't get the job done for stdcall functions. You need to stub out the functions in that case.

Comment: There is nothing in that article that says it will not work with stdcall functions. Considering that the entire Win32 API (save for a few functions) uses stdcall, so it would be stupid for it NOT to support stdcall. Besides, even if you go the stub approach, you still use the LIB utilty to compile the actual .lib file using the compiled stub .obj file, so my answer still stands.

Comment: From the article "Specifically, the functions need to have been
declared to use the C calling convention." The Win32 .lib files can be built from source since MS have that. No need there to reverse engineer the .lib files. When I last looked at this, the only solution I found was stubbing. For x86 you can use implib then omf2coff IIRC correctly. For x64 I think stubbing is needed.

Comment: And yes, you can use cl + lib but the key is stubbing. Which you've not mentioned since you believe it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

With `__declspec(dllimport)` a `__imp__` before the named method is set.

In the generated delphi `CheckFunctions.dll` there is only a function named `CheckResult` .
VS C++ 2010 is looking for `__imp__CheckResult` . Therefore, the linker VS C++ can not find this function.

**You have to create a .lib file.**
With the program `lib.exe` this .lib file can be created very easily.
Run LIB.exe from the Visual-studio command-prompt.

LIB creates standard libraries, import libraries, and export files you can use with LINK when building a program.

[Overview of LIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xb6w1f8.aspx)

If we have created, with the Visual-studio command-prompt>

```
C:\VisualStudio100\VC>lib /def:C:\CheckFunctions.def /OUT:C:\CheckFunctions.lib
```

the `CheckFunctions.lib` file `__imp__CheckResult` can be found.

[image]

You can test it with following steps
with Delphi5 and Win xp 32 it works.

**CheckFunctions.dpr**

```
library CheckFunctions;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.RES}

function CheckResult:integer; stdcall;
begin
   result:=12000;
end;

exports
CheckResult;

begin
end.
```

Create the def file
**CheckFunctions.def**

```
EXPORTS
CheckResult
```

Create the lib file
**Visual Studio command**

```
C:\Programme\VisualStudio100\VC>lib /def:C:\pathToProject\CheckFunctions.def /OUT:C:\pathToProject\CheckFunctions.lib
```

Copy `CheckFunctions.exp` and `CheckFunctions.lib` to
your Visual C++ 2010 Project folder

**Visual C++ 2010 CallDll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MY_DLL __declspec(dllimport)

extern "C"
{
MY_DLL int CheckResult();
} ;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int myint = CheckResult();
    printf ("Decimals: %d \n", myint );
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
if you want it with __stdcall

**NEW Visual C++ 2010 CallDll.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MY_DLL __declspec(dllimport)

extern "C"
{
MY_DLL int __stdcall CheckResult();
} ;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int myint = CheckResult();
    printf ("Decimals: %d \n", myint );
    return 0;
}
```

change delphi exports

```
exports
CheckResult name 'CheckResult@0';
```

Change
**CheckFunctions.def**

```
EXPORTS
CheckResult@0
```

- Create a new CheckFunctions.lib

That works too.

Comment: The calling convention doesn't match. And why are you not explaining anything? Please explain what the problem is that the asker is facing.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong, and the calling convention still does not match. Did you think my answer was wrong?

Comment: I don't see how that could help. The C++ linker still needs an import lib.

Comment: That's why I'm creating a `CheckFunctions.lib` in my answer look at "Create the lib file".

Comment: The __imp__XXX is not a DLL entry point. It's the name of the stub in the import lib.

Comment: I know ! What does in OP's question mean ? `unresolved external symbol __imp_CheckResult referenced in function` . Therefore you must create a .lib file with the Visual Command : `lib /def:F:\stack\DllCall\CheckFunctions.def /OUT:F:\stack\DllCall\CheckFunctions.lib` .

Comment: I said all that long ago. I also linked to an article that says your use of lib only works for cdecl functions. The question uses stdcall. I've told you twice now that your answer gets calling convention wrong. Your C++ code uses cdecl instead of stdcall. You need to create stubs as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please look at my Update with `__stdcall`. Works the same.

Comment: Well yes, but you need to decorate the names now with stdcall decoration. This is what you avoid with stubbing.