# Implement VB.NET Interface Class in C++.NET (2010)

Tags: c++, vb.net, interface

I wonder how I can import an Interface Class in C++.NET which was written in VB.NET.

The Dll contains only a Interface class. If I write "Implement iInterface" in VB.NET, it'll load all Functions and Methods from the Interface.dll.

But how can I do this in C++.NET?

This is what the Interface.dll looks like:

```
Public Interface IPlugin
    Function CreateInstance( _
            ByRef pntMemory As MemoryArbiter, _
            ByRef pntMessageQueue As clsMessageQueue, _
            ByRef pntGPIO As clsGPIO, _
            ByRef pntProgramSettings As Types, _
            ByRef pntDisplayDriver As DisplayDriver _
        ) As Boolean

    Function DeleteInstance() As Boolean

    Sub Main_Loop()
    Sub ForceUnload()
    Sub Interrupt()
End Interface
```

This structure has to be imported to the c++ code.

In VB.NET it looks like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Application

Imports Plugin_Interface
Imports SharedLibrary
Imports SharedLibrary.DisplayDriver

<Export(GetType(IPlugin))>
Public Class cPlugin
    Implements IPlugin

    '.... Class functions come here
```

I, however, just need a tanslation of the file above so I can import the C++ DLL via MEF in my VB.NET 2010 Application.

Hope someone knows how to handle this ... :)

Comment: Probably related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041149/how-to-dllimport-in-microsoft-visual-c

Comment: Hey Alex, sorry but doesn't seem so.

Comment: Does no one have an idea?