# Using DLL in C++ Win32 applicaiton

Tags: c++, dll, win32gui

I have the library called `Serial.dll` that containts the file `Serial.def` that looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
    ValidateSerial
    GenerateSerial
```

I want to import the function `GenerateSerial` in my C++ Win32 application. I searched on the internet topics about using DLLs but I can't get the idea... Can anybody help me?

Comment: Three things: 1. include the header, 2. link against the .lib, 3. put the .dll into your program's working directory.

Comment: [This will give you info, what you looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922580/import-a-dll-with-c-win32)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info you provided only tells two funciton names. You can obtain their address doing `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  But to make any use of them you need to know the proper signature, and the rules for the arguments and return values.

Without documentation (or a .h file) you can't go very far.

Comment: what is DOX? and if the `.h` file helps me, then provide me the information I need please!