# How to call the .cpp file in MQL5?

Tags: c++, dll, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to call the `DLL` file so that I can use the function from the dll. But I failed. See the error I came across:

```
#import "BPNN1.dll"
string Train(
   double &inpTrain[], // Input training data (1D array carrying 2D data, old first)
   double &outTarget[],// Output target data for training (2D data as 1D array, oldest 1st)
   double &outTrain[], // Output 1D array to hold net outputs from training
   int    ntr,        // # of training sets
   int    UEW,        // Use Ext. Weights for initialization (1=use extInitWt, 0=use rnd)
   double &extInitWt[],// Input 1D array to hold 3D array of external initial weights
   double &trainedWt[],// Output 1D array to hold 3D array of trained weights
    int    numLayers,  // # of layers including input, hidden and output
    int    &lSz[],      // # of neurons in layers. lSz[0] is # of net inputs
    int    AFT,        // Type of neuron activation function (0:sigm, 1:tanh, 2:x/(1+x))
    int    OAF,        // 1 enables activation function for output layer; 0 disables
    int    nep,        // Max # of training epochs
    double maxMSE      // Max MSE; training stops once maxMSE is reached
    );

string Test(
   double &inpTest[],  // Input test data (2D data as 1D array, oldest first)
   double &outTest[],  // Output 1D array to hold net outputs from training (oldest first)
   int    ntt,        // # of test sets
   double &extInitWt[],// Input 1D array to hold 3D array of external initial weights
    int    numLayers,  // # of layers including input, hidden and output
    int    &lSz[],      // # of neurons in layers. lSz[0] is # of net inputs
   int    AFT,        // Type of neuron activation function (0:sigm, 1:tanh, 2:x/(1+x))
    int    OAF         // 1 enables activation function for output layer; 0 disables
    );
#import
```

Error:
[image: resource image]

So this means that the dll is failing to load and read. So Is there a way I can include the `.cpp` source file in my MQL5 program and use it? Kindly, suggest me the way out.

Comment: #import "BPNN1.dll" and cannot load BPNNl.dll or it just looks like last letter is small L ?

Comment: `2018.04.11 05:02:55.935 2018.01.01 00:00:00   Cannot load 'C:\Users\AIM\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Tester\D0E8209F77C8CF37AD8BF550E51FF075\Agent-127.0.0.1-3000\MQL5\Indicators\BPNN\BPNN1.dll' [126]` I guess this is something not understood.

Comment: That is not small L. It is 1 (one)

Comment: Already looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922580/import-a-dll-with-c-win32 ?